# The best practices for a rating bar/slider/buttons

Tags: usability, interaction-design, controls, input, ratings

I need to make a rating scale input device that satisfies the following requirements:

1) Each value must be associated with a number to the user.
2) It must be immediately clear that this thing measures a continuum.
3) It can't be pre-selected (making an actual slider all but impossible)
4) It must be adaptable to a number of different variables of differing levels of significance to the user.

I have attached my first attempt. It needs help.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking exactly.  Right now it looks like a "please review my design" type question.  I can see a good question in there, but not as it is asked right now, so please edit the post and make the specific question clearer.

Comment: I'd say the white-space between de boxes kinda works against the idea of a continuum, but otherwise I think you nailed it. Is there a problem to solve in this?

Comment: Koen I think that actually gets to the heart of the matter. How to communicate continuum while maintaining a pseudo-Metro style (which tends to prize each discrete object having its own color).

Comment: When you say that you need to create an input device, is it actually a physical device? Or if it is an interface then I don't see why you need to restrict yourself to those requirements (or if you do please provide the reasons).

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

- Join the buttons with some sort of bar.
- Crank down the color. It's hard to spot what's selected
- I think the transition from saturation = click me to saturation = currently selected option is confusing. I'd represent the transition with two different metaphors.

Here's a quick idea:

[image: continuum of buttons]

Answer (score 0):

Use a **linear gradient** to represent whatever colors you want and the use **markers** to represent points.

[image]

Something like this with markings for different points rather than entire boxes for individual points.

**When you use box, you are essentially creating a discrete value rather than a continuous scale.**