# What's the best design to get a number from a small range from user?

Tags: website-design, forms, web-app, input-fields

I have a system where I have to get a number, between 1 and 10, from the user in a web application. (The actual use case is the user has to say which group he is from, and group names are numbers from 1 to 10)

What design would result in the best user experience for something like this? A radio button?

[image]

A radio input with visual feedback on selected number?

[image]

Or maybe a normal select with redundant ("th Group") info?

[image]

Or another option?

Comment: Hi T., what is the context?

Comment: I have to get the fiscal region (IRS related) where the user lives, which are numbered from 1 to 10 in my country (first region, second region, ..., tenth region) when the user signs up for the website.

Comment: Wow, I would say away from this approach as it looks like a Likert scale which is commonly used for rating. Maybe a nice map would work or a drop-down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid abstracting the label from the control wherever possible. That is, avoid separating the control and the label that describes the control's state because that forces the user to look in two different places in order to understand what's going on. Instead combine them so that the control clearly describes its own state.

In this particular situation, I would want to have the number directly above each of the radio buttons or use a custom control that presents this more elegantly, like the one below that was given as an example in another question ([The best practices for a rating bar/slider/buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/the-best-practices-for-a-rating-bar-slider-buttons)).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You think a radio button would be better in this case than a select with redundant info in this case? (Added a picture to the question with what I had in mind for the select)

Comment: @t.pimentel I think if the groups have descriptive names a dropdown might be better but if they are just numbers I would use a radio list.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Group is not redundant and also in line with the options.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I would also suggest you carefully consider the order of the values.

Ordering values from 10 to 1 (instead of from 1 to 10) leads users to give an higher average rating (you can find more informations [in this answer I wrote a couple of days ago](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/63580/52705)).

You may also want to have a look at the **[primacy effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primacy_effect#Primacy_effect)**:

> a cognitive bias that results in a subject recalling primary information presented better than information presented later on.

Comment: This question is not about ratings, I'm actually trying to avoid that my interface looks too much like one, if I can.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that - my fault. Thanks for giving me your feedback.